# How can i change the text position in a div?

Tags: html, css

i have a `section`, and inside of it an `ul` with 4 `li`. In each `li` a `div` that are going to be cards. I want to centralize the text inside the div and put it closer to the bottom.
I tried using `float: left`, and then change the position with margin top and left, but i cannot centralize it.

```css
.cards2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.list2 {
  list-style: none;
}

.list2 li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.cardd2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.list2 p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="cards2">
  <ul class="list2">
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card1">
        <p>Sobre mim</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card2">
        <p>Projetos</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card3">
        <p>Habilidades</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card4">
        <p>Contato</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: By centralize the text inside the div do you mean center the text vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these to `.cardd2`

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-evenly;
```

take note of them young padawan, you're gonna use it a lot

also add `margin-bottom: 1vh;` for separation

```css
.cards2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.list2 {
  list-style: none;
}

.list2 li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.cardd2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
}

.list2 p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="cards2">
  <ul class="list2">
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card1">
        <p>Sobre mim</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card2">
        <p>Projetos</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card3">
        <p>Habilidades</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card4">
        <p>Contato</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Like this:-

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.list2 {
  display: flex;
  positition: absloute;
  align items: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="cards2">
  <ul class="list2">
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card1">
        <p>Sobre mim</p>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card2">
        <p>Projetos</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card3">
        <p>Habilidades</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card4">
        <p>Contato</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Please take more care answering. You are not spelling absolute correctly and you could have removed the `>` from OPs original code and included the relevant CSS when you made the snippet

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the code that you want.

I assume that you need to have the text inside `li`s to be centered vertically and want it to be a bit down to the bottom.

```css
.cards2{
    text-align: center;
}

.list2{
    list-style: none;
    

}

.list2 li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.cardd2{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(107, 255, 240);

    display: flex;
        align-content: center;
        margin: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.list2 p{
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    margin-top:100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="cards2">
  <ul class="list2">
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card1"><p>Sobre mim</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card2"><p>Projetos</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card3"><p>Habilidades</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card4"><p>Contato</p></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `.cardd2`:

> ```
> margin-bottom: .25rem;
> display: flex;
> align-items: center;
> justify-content: center;
> ```

```css
.cards2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.list2 {
    list-style: none;
}

.list2 li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.cardd2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-bottom: .25rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.list2 p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="cards2">
  <ul class="list2">
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card1"><p>Sobre mim</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card2"><p>Projetos</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card3"><p>Habilidades</p></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="cardd2" id="card4"><p>Contato</p></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```